# Is there a good limit for max line length for minified javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a web app that is bundled and minified to 770 KB total with all the frameworks and plugins included. That's about 10+ times larger than a jquery library. I wonder if there is a good max line length for minified javascript. I heard that there is some noticeable impact when a minified css file is too long on one line but I couldn't find any such blogs or articles on this matter. Does anyone have experience with this and could shed some light on whether there is a performance impact of line length in a very large javascript file?

Comment: I have noticed that if a line is too long then I can't use the Developer Tools to search the JS. It would freeze if I tried. As far as code execution, everything seemed fine.

Comment: I doubt compilers care about line break characters.  Perhaps if you display the code under a debugger or *View Source* console, that could have a problem but then you probably don't want to be looking at minified code anyway.

Comment: more concerned about loading and rendering time atm. I ask because jquery seems to set one line at 32kb, and I was curious as to why it isn't on 1 line of code but I couldn't find out

Comment: Does the user really need all 770KB from the start!? That is a big chunk to load/parse right up front.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max line length for CSS files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619209/max-line-length-for-css-files)