# Max line length for CSS files

Tags: html, css, sass

Do browsers limit the length of a line in a CSS file?

I'm [having a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615404/some-styles-not-rendered-in-the-browser-with-sass-style-compressed) where certain CSS styles are not being recognized by the browser *after* I minify the code using `sass --style compressed`.

It works fine when the styles are on individual lines. And it *still* works fine if I enter a line break in strategic places in the minified CSS. So this tells me there is not a problem with the way the CSS is written or the way that the minification is happening - rather it seems like the browser just doesn't like something about the format minified code.

Comment: I dont think its a browser issue. Does it happen in every browser? Can we see the compiled css file? My first guess is, that some quotes ('') are  not closed right and after a linebreak it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Have you [validated](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) the minified CSS? Have you tried another minifier?

Comment: Note: OP says the minified CSS file works once he adds a few line breaks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some styles not rendered in the browser with sass --style compressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615404/some-styles-not-rendered-in-the-browser-with-sass-style-compressed). Please, if you decide to ask a question that is highly related to another one still in progress, hyperlink the earlier one, so people can see what gave rise to the query, and how the current answers are doing.

Comment: @halfer I will add the link because I agree they're related, but it's really not a duplicate question. This questions is about browser requirements / limits.

Comment: @Stijn I tried compiling the SCSS from the command line as well as using CodeKit's GUI to minify the code. Not 100% what CodeKit is doing under the hood.

Comment: @Stijn I ran it through the W3C validator and it threw 2 errors but was completely unhelpful with identifying what they were. Just globbed the full CSS into one block. Can you recommend a CSS validator that doesn't suck?

Comment: @antpaw I think your missing `"` theory is a good one. Any thoughts on how to strategically find it? I'm not having much luck with W3C validator... but something tells me there's a strategic way to find this needle in the haystack.

Comment: @SDP just drop a line break after 50% of the line-length (assume it worked) then 75% (assume it didn't worked) 62,5% and so on.

Answer (score 7):

Firewalls and proxies sometimes corrupt or ignore large CSS files with very long lines.

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq#linefeeds

> **Why are there random line feeds in compiled scripts?**
>
> The Closure
>   Compiler intentionally adds line breaks every 500 characters or so.
>   Firewalls and proxies sometimes corrupt or ignore large JavaScript
>   files with very long lines. Adding line breaks every 500 characters
>   prevents this problem. Removing the line breaks has no effect on a
>   script's semantics. The impact on code size is small, and the Compiler
>   optimizes line break placement so that the code size penalty is even
>   smaller when files are gzipped.

The article directly applies to javascript files. I believe it is applies to CSS files as well.

Comment: This seems likely, just tested a css file which was one line with 68363 characters and all styles were applied. Would be interested to hear what OP's environment is

Comment: @JoshDavenport You are right. For instance, css of Bootstrap 4.5.3 contains 6 lines and 6th includes about 160k characters.